Synchronization with Phaser in java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class FooRunner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    Runnable first =
        () -> {
          try {
            foo.first(() -> System.out.println("first"));
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
        };

    Runnable second =
        () -> {
          try {
            foo.second(() -> System.out.println("second"));
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
        };
    Runnable third =
        () -> {
          try {
            foo.third(() -> System.out.println("third"));
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
        };

    executors.submit(third);
    executors.submit(first);
    executors.submit(second);

    executors.shutdown();
  }
}

Implementation of synchronization with help of Phaser.
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;

public class Foo {

  private final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);

  public Foo() {}

  public void first(Runnable printFirst) throws InterruptedException {
    printFirst.run();
    phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
  }

  public void second(Runnable printSecond) throws InterruptedException {
    phaser.awaitAdvance(1); // wait for first to complete
    printSecond.run();
    phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
  }

  public void third(Runnable printThird) throws InterruptedException {
    phaser.awaitAdvance(2); // wait for second to complete
    printThird.run();
    phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
  }
}

Expected behaviour here is to print
first
second
third

but threads are not waiting on phaser. Is current implementation wrong usage of phaser ?
Note: Phaser is not right choice to bring sequential synchronized behaviour among threads.

Phaser phaser = new Phaser(4); // 3 threads + main thread

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    new Thread(
            () -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println(
                        "Waiting Before Phase 1 for " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); // Wait for other threads

                    Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
                    System.out.println("Before Phase 2 for " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    // Phase 2
                    phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); // Wait for next phase
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            })
        .start();
}

phaser.arriveAndDeregister(); // Deregister main thread



I'm only guessing, but your threads take nearly zero time to complete. Maybe put a sleep in each thread.

IMHO you misunderstand how Phaser works. One thing is that arrive() explicitly mentions that [I]t is a usage error for an unregistered party to invoke this method - but you never register your threads.  And advancing only happens when all registered parties have called arrive()

@ThomasKläger yes, that I also believe, trying different approaches/modification, Will update the post If I am able to get desired result.
